# how to maintan check status of a check-box even when the component is initialized

Tags: html, angular, typescript

as for the below posted html code, it is linked to a button so that when the button is clicked it sets `showVisOptionsLayout` to true and thus the below posted html code appears.
the problem i am facing is, when i click that button the `.ts` code is called and the `init()` is called "as shown below" causing the check-boxes to be initialized.
what i want to achieve is, to maintain the state of the check-boxes even when the `init()` is called. in other words, lets consider the following scenario:

1-the user clicked the button attached the belwo posted `html` code

2-`init()` method will be called

3- as a result, all the check-boxes will be un-checked

4-the user chose to check the first check-box which is "iVisualizationOperationPasser.areaOfCoverage"

5-as a resutl to step 4, the check-box will be checked and the menu will disappear "it will disappear because i desingned it like this"

6-when the uset click the button attached to the below posted 'html' again, `init()` method will be invoked and all the check-boxes will be un-checked.hence, the most recent state of the check-box `iVisualizationOperationPasser.areaOfCoverage` which was set to
true is lost.

i want to maintain the most recent state of the check-boxes even if the button attached to the below posted `html` is called.i want to achive that the check-boxes can be uncheck only when the user chooses to do so

please let me know how to maintain the most recent state of the check-boxes even if the `init()` is called several times

**Note**

```
for each clikc on the button attached to the below posted `html`, once `showVisOptionsLayout` will be `true causing `init()` to be invoked, and when it is clicked again it will cause `showVisOptionsLayout` to be set to `false`,hence all the check-boxes will be set
to false. 
each time the button is clicked, it toggles that state of `showVisOptionsLayout`
```

**html**:

```
<div id="idMainContainer" *ngIf="showVisOptionsLayout">
<div id=idDivider1>
    <hr class="solid">
</div>

<clr-checkbox-container id="idCheckBoxContainer">
    <clr-checkbox-wrapper id="idDWrapperForAreaOfCoveragecheckbox">
        <input [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="iVisualizationOperationPasser.areaOfCoverage" name="checkboxGroupForVisualizationOption" type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (click)="onOpAreaOfCoverageSelected($event)" [checked]="showAreaOfCoverageOption"/>
            <label id="idLabelVisOpAreaOfCoverageTitle">
                {{ "VISUALIZATION_OPTION.AREA_OF_COVERAGE" | translate }} 
            </label>
    </clr-checkbox-wrapper>
   
    <clr-checkbox-wrapper id="idDWrapperForAverageHeightscheckbox">
        <input [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="iVisualizationOperationPasser.averageHeights" name="checkboxGroupForVisualizationOption" type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (click)="onOpAverageHeightsSelected($event)" [checked]="showAverageHeightsOption"/>
            <label id="idLabelVisOpAverageHeightsTitle">
                {{ "VISUALIZATION_OPTION.AVERAGE_HEIGHTS" | translate }} 
            </label>
    </clr-checkbox-wrapper>
    <clr-checkbox-wrapper id="idDWrapperForInterceptioncheckbox">
        <input [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="iVisualizationOperationPasser.interception" name="checkboxGroupForVisualizationOption" type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (click)="onOpInterceptionSelected($event)" [checked]="showInterceptionOption"/>
            <label id="idLabelVisOpInterceptionTitle">
                {{ "VISUALIZATION_OPTION.INTERCEPTION" | translate }} 
            </label>
    </clr-checkbox-wrapper>
    <!-- <clr-checkbox-wrapper id="idDWrapperForEndangeredAreascheckbox">
        <input [value]="4" [(ngModel)]="iVisualizationOperationPasser.EndangeredAreas" name="checkboxGroupForVisualizationOption" type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (click)="onOpEndangeredAreasSelected($event)" [checked]="showEndangeredAreasOption"/>
            <label id="idLabelVisOpEndangeredAreasTitle">
                {{ "VISUALIZATION_OPTION.ENDANGERED_AREAS" | translate }} 
            </label>
    </clr-checkbox-wrapper> -->
</clr-checkbox-container>


<div id=idDivider2>
    <hr class="solid">
</div>
```

**ngOnIniit()**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log("ngOnInit")
this.init()
}

private init(){

    this.iVisualizationOperationPasser.areaOfCoverage = false
    this.iVisualizationOperationPasser.averageHeights = flse
    this.iVisualizationOperationPasser.interception = false
```

}

Comment: `(ngModelChange)` Adding event Listeners

Comment: @thanks, can you please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div  *ngFor="let item of checkArr">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checkbox" (ngModelChange)="changeValue($event)">{{item.name}}
</div>
```

```
    checkArr = [
        {name: 'onw', value: 1, checkbox: false},
        {name: 'two', value: 2, checkbox: false},
        {name: 'three', value: 3, checkbox: false},
    ]
  changeValue($event: any) {
        console.log(this.checkArr);
    }
```